# Draw a vertical line

Tags: macos, swift3, draw

I want to put an image (I will create) in my status bar app and this image should made of vertical line but I don't now how to draw them.

Comment: Use a custom `NSView` as view of the status item and override `drawRect` to draw the image and the line. However this makes you responsible to handle all keyboard / mouse events and the highlighting yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found

```
let graphWidth: CGFloat = 22.0;
let graphHeight: CGFloat = 22.0
let size = NSMakeSize( graphWidth, graphHeight )
let image = NSImage(size: size)
image.lockFocus()

let path = NSBezierPath()
path.move(to: NSPoint(x: 20.0, y: 0))
path.line(to: NSPoint(x: 20.0, y: 20.0))
path.stroke()
image.unlockFocus()

statusItem.image = image
```